# TP-LINK TL-WN722N bad connection quality

Tags: wireless, adapter

I have a TP-LINK TL-WN722N wi-fi adapter, and I suffer from bad connection quality on ubuntu. Dowload speeds may vary from 3 MB/s down to 40 kB/s, ping is unstable and online games are unplayable. On windows it works flawlessly. Any ideas, what may cause the problem?

Comment: is your router configured for wireless `N`? What is your wifi device in laptop (`sudo lshw -c network`)

Comment: configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=1.3 ip=192.168.0.104 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
It runs on N mode, wifi hotspot is on bgn mode. Anyway same config on windows works perfectly, but on ubuntu not

Comment: Try this - [atheros wireless ar9285 driver](http://askubuntu.com/a/334250) , Please change the driver name from `ath9k` to `ath9k_htc` in above steps.  (If those steps doesn't work, use `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k_htc.conf`  and reboot to revert the changes)

Comment: Tried this, didn't help unfortunately. I've also tried to download the latest .fw files from kernel web site for my adapter. They didn't help as well. I guess I'll have to give up on linux for a while unless I buy a new adapter

Comment: Try disabling n mode in router

Comment: Tried this as well, no luck. I think it's an issue which should be reported, but I have no idea where to report. 
And BTW, I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround, I used [Windows Wireless Drivers tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/ndisgtk/)

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```

I used windows XP x64 driver, works fine.