# No gateway ping in ubuntu and fedora, but ok on windows

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, ping, gateway

I am facing a confusing problem. while using my home Wifi  on ubuntu 14.04 amd64, my internet connection suddenly gives no response but in notification area it is shown as connected.

I switched my wifi on and off, it connects to my device but still no response.

My gateway is `192.168.1.1`, my mask is `255.255.255.0`, my IP is `192.168.1.38` but when i ping the gateway **no result** comes back.

I restarted couple of times, same problem.

Then I restarted and boot into my fedora 20 x86_64, same problem.

Then I restarted and boot into Windows, no problem there. everything works.

Then I restarted and boot into ubuntu again, the problem is fixed!!!!

This has happend to me so many times at home.

Can anyone tell me what is going on? What extra information i should search about?

---

**Edit:** I started downloading something and it happened again.

here is my `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:0a:a9:bf:f6:34  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:563 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:563 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:49860 (49.8 KB)  TX bytes:49860 (49.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:17:fe:fb:b9:7a  
          inet addr:192.168.1.38  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c617:feff:fefb:b97a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7495 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9052410 (9.0 MB)  TX bytes:920101 (920.1 KB)
```

and here is my `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

I also checked these commands after and before mysterious disconnection, i think results are the same.

---

**Edit:** I also stopped `ufw` and `iptables` services and then,

here is my `iptables -L -n -v`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 352 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 21 packets, 1764 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

and here is my `arp -a`

```
? (192.168.1.1) at ec:43:f6:fb:76:64 [ether] on wlan0
```

---

**Edit:** here is my `lspci -vvnn | grep -i wireless -A 10`:

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at f0100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: Try to add the results of `ifconfig -a` and `route -n` when the problem occurs and when all is working ok. I still have problems with my wireless router where at times I have to set the routes statically.

Comment: @Rmano I added them to the question.

Comment: Your IP isn't .44 but .38 (wifi)

Comment: @Jan DHCP gives me different IPs. it does not matter because it is the same with static IPs. i also tested 192.168.1.4

Comment: The routing table is ok. Strange. Thinking...

Comment: perhaps a driver issue? `lspci -vvnn | grep -i wireless -A 10` should give us plenty of info to work with.

Comment: can you ping your machine from another host on the network when this happens?

Comment: @wxl I added the command results to the question.

Comment: Can you try the steps in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/334250/52726?