# Wireless Connection drops every few days

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

My wireless connection drops every few days, and to fix it I usually have to restart the computer, connect via ethernet, run software update, restart my router, and then my computer reconnects.

I ran **lspci**:

```
habib@habib-UL30V:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev  03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI  Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M-E LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
habib@habib-UL30V:~$
```

Please help as I am kind of new to Ubuntu

P.S. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (laptop system), also [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9888784/) is the link to what happens when I run the script mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Have you verified that the problem isn't your router?

Comment: Yes every other computer works perfectly

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: @ElderGeek I have updated the question (at the bottom)

Comment: @ElderGeek this is a laptop system

Comment: In most cases you can still reseat the mini PCI card. Without the model of your laptop I can't tell you how to do that but your manual should have the information necessary...

Comment: @ElderGeek do you mean take out the card and put it back in?

Comment: Yes. Unplug if plugged into AC, remove the battery, remove the card, then reverse the process

Comment: @ElderGeek I will respond to you after I have done this, sadly I do not had access to the computer right now, I will get to access to it in 6 hours, then I will perform the process mentioned above.

Comment: @ElderGeek I'm sorry, I tried to reseat my PCI card but failed for various reasons, is there no other way to do this?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334200/atheros-wireless-ar9285-driver     Also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866335

Comment: @ElderGeek The second link seems to have fixed it, will confirm after a few days, when i do confirm, please mark this question as solved if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following packages:
network-manager-gnome

Install the following packages:
python-wicd
wicd 
wicd-daemon
wicd-gtk

[Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866335](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866335)

If this works for you please upvote/mark as accepted. If not comment and we will try to help further.