# 14.10 - Wifi stopped working on two laptops, both with Atheros AR9285 network adapters

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10, atheros

Yesterday morning, two laptops I'm currently using wouldn't connect to a wifi network anymore. One is my Eee PC 1015T on Xubuntu 14.10; the other one is an old Acer laptop on which I've recently (five days before) installed Ubuntu 14.10. Both laptops have an Atheros AR9285 wireless adapter. Both have the same issue, with apparently the same symptoms: the network indicator blinks for a while, then displays a "Disconnected" tooltip, then tries again to connect some time later, etc. I've tried several wifi networks, with and without authentication methods: no one would work. Ethernet seems to work fine.

I've checked my update history in Software Center, and there were no significant updates made on any of the two computers. Here are two wireless-info.txt, one [generated on the Acer laptop](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10249473/), the other [on my Eee PC](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10249585/), both using the script provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the wifi router settings to eliminate TKIP, you want to have WPA2-AES which will show up in `iwlist scan` and WPA2 Version 1 with Group Cipher: CCMP and Pairwise Cipher: CCMP

Data rate will not go higher than 11g speed with TKIP, and linux usually has problems when it is enabled

Comment: I've done just that on my "Box Fibre de SFR" control panel (following [those steps](http://assistance.sfr.fr/runtime/internet-et-box/box-tv-fibredesfr/modifier-type-securite-wifi-box-tv-fibre.html)). That seems to have resolved the issue: now, both of my computers can use the wifi again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

- [atheros wireless ar9285 driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334200/atheros-wireless-ar9285-driver)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1286503